# updating old app from appcompat 21 to 28 fails

Tags: android, sdk, android-appcompat

Morning,
I am trying to update an old android app that was originally built with a target of sdk 21. I am changing that to sdk 28 but when I change the corresponding appcompat version, I no longer have access to the ActionBarActivity that my app is based on.

I read that you have to change the [ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity](https://inducesmile.com/android-tutorials-for-nigerian-developer/how-to-fix-android-support-v7-actionbaractivity-is-deprecated/) after sdk 21 but that didn't work either.

Here what my gradle file looks like (I know compile is depreciated, one thing at a time :)  ):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tacostudios.tacohunter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
}
```

on the import statement I am getting an error: 
cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to migrate to AndroidX, using Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX in Android Studio.

Comment: can't migrate to android x until sdk is version 28, but when it is sdk 28 the app fails to build.

Answer (score 0):

For others coming back to an old project and not remembering anything, here is the order I had to do items to get everything working:

Import all of the missing packages to run the app. In my case there were only 2.
Do not update sdk yet
make sure app builds and runs, ignore warnings about sdk versions.
update gradle package
increase sdk version and appcompat versions
change actionbaractivity to appcompatactivity

When I did these in a different order (like updating gradle first) things went wonky.